# Nested Mathematical Functions

Tags: amsmath

This question has bugged me for a while. I want to write a nested function, `f(g(x))`. If I naively enter it:

```
\begin{align}
    f(g(x))=y
\end{align}
```

[image: Naive typeset]

The problem is that each and every parenthesis is the same size as all of the others. Shouldn't the outer parentheses be larger? But if I do this:

```
\begin{align}
    f\left(g(x)\right)=y
\end{align}
```

[image]

Now it looks even less like the functions are nested. What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Besides @Steven's answer, you can set `\delimitershortfall` to be negative.

Comment: @Symbol1 Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Nope, the first comment comes from the canned welcome message. [Here](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/math/voss/mathmode/) is a comprehensive introduction of math mode.

Comment: Instead of using ever larger brackets, it's often better to alternate in a fixed sequence, e.g. h[g\{f(x)\}], before increasing bracket sizes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are enlarged grouping symbols available as `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg`, and `\Bigg`.  A following `l` or `r` indicates left or right (which helps allocate the proper surround spacing), and then follow it up with the grouping symbol itself.

Obviously the `\displaystyle` example [p(q(f(g(h(x)))))] in my MWE is to make an exaggerated point.  I am not actually suggesting it for the case given (see answer SUPPLEMENT for alternative).

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$f\bigl(g(x)\bigr)$ 
\[
p\Biggl(q\biggl(f\Bigl(g\bigl(h(x)\bigr)\Bigr)\biggr)\Biggr)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In a comment, Gonzalo suggests using the `mathtools` package to declare delimiter pairs, which in his MWE, he calls `\Comp`.  Then, using `\Comp[<size>]{...}` will place the specified size delimiters around the embraced quantity.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\Comp{(}{)} 
\begin{document} 
$f\Comp[\big]{g(x)}$ 
\[ 
p\Comp[\Bigg]{ q\Comp[\bigg]{ f\Comp[\Big]{g\Comp[\big]{h(x} } } } 
\] 
\end{document}
```

---

SUPPLEMENT:

If one truly needed a more finely graded scaling of adjacent delimiters, my `scalerel` package could be used in that regard.  Here, I add 0.4pt height above and below each "unit" to govern the size of the next delimiter.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}
\stackMath
\ignoremathstyle
\newcommand\Comp[1]{\scaleleftright{(}{\addstackgap[.4pt]{#1}}{)}}
\begin{document} 
$f\Comp{g(x)}$ 
\[ 
p\Comp{ q\Comp{ f\Comp{g\Comp{h(x)} } } } 
\] 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could also suggest the `mathtools` approach? `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\Comp{(}{)}

\begin{document}

$f\Comp[\big]{g(x)}$ 

\[
p\Comp[\Bigg]{
  q\Comp[\bigg]{
    f\Comp[\Big]{g\Comp[\big]{h(x}
    }
  }
}
\]

\end{document}` I was going to add an answer but since you've already done it, no point in posting mine.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks.  I have added your approach.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina How does mathtools work differently?

Comment: @Joel `mathtools` merely introduces a syntax that some may find preferable, rather than having to keep track of individual left and right delimiters.

Comment: @Joel The code is shorter and you have also a starred version `\Comp*` which applies the `\left`, `\right` construct in those (few) cases in which it might be required.