# Adaptive parentheses at equations

Tags: equations, parentheses

Is there a command that adapts automatically the size of the parentheses at the terms of the equations?

For example, in my ocasion I used `\Big(` but it's seems not enough. 
I think could be more bigger.

[image]

Comment: I think you are looking for `\left(` and `\right)`

Comment: Usually it's better to choose the size yourself. There's a difference in spacing between left and right delimiters, so you should use the pairs `\bigl...\bigr`, `\Bigl...\Bigr`,  `\biggl...\biggr`, `\Biggl...\Biggr`.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267171/nested-mathematical-functions and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360996/universal-parentheses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\left` and `\right` to wrap brackets. In your case you'd write

```
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = - \left( u \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + ... \right) + ...
```

where I haven't typed out your full equation but I hope you can see where it's going from here.

Answer (score 3):

There's a difference in spacing between left and right delimiters. In general you obtain a better result choosing yourself the delimiters size, so you should use pairs `\Bigl/\Bigr` and the like. There 4 sizes for manual adjustment:  `\bigl/\bigr`, `\Bigl/\Bigr`,  `\biggl/\biggr`, `\Biggl/\Biggr`. Here is an example, in which I also loaded the `esdiff` package, which simplifies the typing of derivatives, partial or not:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{esdiff}

\begin{document}

\[ \diffp{u}{t} = -\biggl(u\diffp{u}{x} + v\diffp{u}{y}\biggr)-\diffp{P}{x} + \frac{1}{Re}\Bigl(\diffp[2]{u}{x} +\diffp[2]{u}{y} \Bigr)\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]