# Custom size delimters

Tags: math-mode, delimiters, mathtools, newtxmath

I am in the situation where I want delimiters that are bigger that `\big`, but smaller than `\Big` (see example).

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\[\Bigl(\bigl(\text{some formula}\bigr)\Bigr)\]
\end{document}
```

With `newtxmath`, the outside delimiters are a lot bigger than the 
`\big`delimters inside, but I want them only slightly bigger. `scalebox` from the `graphicx`package doesn't seem to be satisfactory.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267171/nested-mathematical-functions

Comment: Using the code under SUPPLEMENT results in differently shaped parentheses with `newtxmath` for me.

Comment: The `scalerel` approach takes the given glyph and either scales or stretches is, which is a different approach than the `\bigg`, etc. approach.  But the scalerel macros also allow constraints (max width in case of scaling and min-aspect ration in the case of stretching).  So for example, try this with SUPPLEMENT code:  `\newcommand\Comp[2][500]{\stretchleftright[#1]{\biggl(}{\addstackgap[.4pt]{#2}}{\biggr)}}`, then, `p\Comp{ q\Comp{ f\Comp{g\Comp{\displaystyle\frac{f}{f}} } } }` as well as `p\Comp{ q\Comp{ f\Comp{g\Comp{h(x)} } } }` look good.

Comment: Thanks a lot! After playing around with the parameters a little, I was able got a good looking result.

Comment: So you can either wait to see if other answers are posted?  Or we can declare your question a duplicate of the one cited?  Or you could post an answer to your own question and accept it?

Comment: I'm satisfied with result from the code that can -- in essence -- be found in the answer you linked, so I'm okay with this being marked as a duplicate.