# How to increase the vertical offset of exponent terms with increasing size of parentheses?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, superscripts, parentheses

I want to be able to write the following expression:

[image]

But have not been able to do so, since all I can get is:

[image]

I do not use the fraction of P/E, but rather just the psi. Can you help?

EDIT: After the suggestion of \left (and \right), I have managed to produce the following:

```
\begin{equation}
\hat{\psi}_{p,t}=n\displaystyle 
\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}\big(\psi_{j,t})^{-1}\big)\right)^{-1}
\end{equation}
```

But it does not seem as if \big has an effect?

[image]

Comment: What is wrong with `\left(`, `\big(`, etc.?

Comment: `\big(`, `\bigg(`, `\Big(`, `\Bigg(`, etc. You have tons of options.

Comment: I added your suggestion, but it does not seem as if \big has any effect? Maybe I haven't understood the command properly

Comment: It _does_ have effects, but the brackets are not really bigger, only slightly. Read my comment above.

Comment: My bad, it just didn't seem as if there was any change initially. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267171/nested-mathematical-functions and  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360996/universal-parentheses,

Comment: Somewhat related are \lgroup and \rgroup from braket and mathabx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to achieve in terms of sizing the inner and outer pairs of parentheses.

As far as I can tell, there is no need whatsoever to increase the size of the inner parentheses, if the term they enclose is `\psi_{j,t}`. For the *outer* parentheses, choose `\biggl(` and `\right)` -- using `\left(` and `\right)` would result in parentheses that are too tall, typographically speaking.

Here, then, is how I would rewrite your equation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\hat{\psi}_{p,t}=n\biggl( \sum_{j=1}^{n} (\psi_{j,t})^{-1} \biggr)^{\!-1}
\]
\end{document}
```